# Чем отличаются 2 метода получения строк (python 3.x)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Чем отличаются:

```
print(open("test.txt","r",encoding="Latin-1").read())
```

от

```
print(open("test.txt","rb").read().decode("Latin-1"))
```

Оно отличается не могу понять чем, при одном случае первое выдает одно, второе выдает совсем другое. При других случаях все одинакового. Помогите разобраться. Зарание спасибо.

Comment: Что выводит-то?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну, трудно работать телепатами...

Возможно, надо учитывать, что текстовый режим чтения файла корректирует последовательности `\r\n`, а `decode()` — нет. Лучше выводить не `print(s)`, а `print(repr(s))`, а то `print()` иногда вот такое выдаст:

```
> print('333\r111')
111
```

Comment: @ Alex Titov что делает последовательности \r\n ?

Comment: @Gleb  при чтении текстового файла  '\r',  '\r\n', по умолчанию превращается в '\n'. См. описание параметра newline у функции open.